# JavaScript, creating new html elements: the content of the new created <td> is inserted in old <td>

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a web page that contains a JavaScript code, what I am trying to do is when ever I click on a button the code creates a new `<tr>` and in each `<tr>` there will be many `<td>` elements.
but the problem is when ever I click on the button the elements are created but the content of each `<td>` is inserted in the cells of the first row `<tr>`.
which means all new `<td>`s are empty.

As an Example: if I click on the button "Ajouter une ligne" twice, it looks like 2 rows are created:
[image]

but if we take a look at the html code, we can see that the second `<tr>` is empty:
[image]

here is the code .js

```
<script>
///////////////
var click=0;
function addform() {
click +=1;
var element = document.getElementById("div1");
//create a tr
var id_tr="tr"+click;
create_tr(element, id_tr);

//create the content of td
 


var designation = document.createElement("INPUT");
textinput(designation, "text" , "designation", "form-control", 
"Désignation",click);

var datef = document.createElement("INPUT");
textinput(datef, "date" , "datefacture", "form-control", "Date de 
Facture",click);

var datep = document.createElement("INPUT");
textinput(datep, "date" , "datepaie", "form-control", "Date de Paie",click);

var mht = document.createElement("INPUT");
textinput(mht, "text" , "mht", "form-control", "Montant HT",click);

var mtva = document.createElement("INPUT");
textinput(mtva, "text" , "mtva", "form-control", "Montant TVA",click);

var mttc = document.createElement("INPUT");
textinput(mttc, "text" , "mttc", "form-control", "Montant TTC",click);

var file = document.createElement("INPUT");
textinput(file, "text" , "file", "form-control", "Choose File",click);

var importer = document.createElement("INPUT");
textinput(importer, "button" , "importer", "btn btn-primary", "Choose 
File",click);


var elmtr=document.getElementById(id_tr);
create_tds(elmtr, designation, 1 );
create_tds(elmtr, datef, 2 );
create_tds(elmtr, datep, 3);
create_tds(elmtr, mht, 4);
create_tds(elmtr, mtva, 5);
create_tds(elmtr, mttc, 6);
create_tds(elmtr, file, 7);
create_tds(elmtr, importer, 8);
}
function create_tr(element, id_tr){
var trr = document.createElement("TR");
trr.setAttribute("id", id_tr);
element.appendChild(trr);

}
function create_tds(elmtr,input_td, clicktd){
var y = document.createElement("TD");
var td="td";
y.setAttribute("id", td+clicktd);
elmtr.appendChild(y);
var elmtd=document.getElementById(td+clicktd);
elmtd.appendChild(input_td);

}
function textinput(x, type, name, classe, placeholder,click){

x.setAttribute("type", type);
x.setAttribute("name", name+click);
x.setAttribute("class", classe);
x.setAttribute("placeholder", placeholder);
if (name=="file") {

    x.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
}
if (type == "button") {
x.setAttribute("value", "importer");    
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: According you screenshot, you have made a basic mistake: An id is a tool to identify each element in the page clearly. Means an id must be unique. The ids for table cells have more than one occurences.

Comment: thank you @reporter, I've corrected the code , and now it works,

Comment: yess of course, please do so .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According you screenshot, you have made a basic mistake: An id is a tool to identify each element in the page clearly. Means an id must be unique. The ids for table cells have more than one occurences.

If you have the chance to use Jquery you can change the ids to a -dummy- css classes. It is valid html code that names of css classes are used multiple times. :-)